# .htaccess invisible redirect to page within subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've tried many options in .htaccess without success. What I want to do is this:

I have Wordpress residing in its own folder, like this: `site.com/folder`

I want all users visiting site.com to be redirected to `site.com/folder/page` but in such a way that the URL doesn't change in the browser. All other URLs, such as `site.com/folder` and `site.com/folder/page1 etc` shouldn't be affected.

How to do this, in as SEO-friendly way as possible?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect a user to a other page from serverside without to show this to the use.
But if you need, you can use the HTML tag `<frame>` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp
But the bad side with this is the use always will be show "site.com" and not the real page.

But I think the best way is to proxy the result, in Apache you can do this by something like this.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/$ folder/page/index.php [L]
```

Comment: That's not proxying, that's just internally rewriting like what the OP asks. The `P` flag hands the request to mod_proxy to be reverse proxied.

Comment: True, no real proxy, but some type, you simluate data exist on A but in real exist in B :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately that rule isn't working. I get Apache server test page.

Comment: Yes, have you check if the RewriteEngine and this modull is load and allow and is use correctly?

Comment: Yes, RewriteEngine is on. I removed '/' from '^/$' but I was always being redirected to 'folder' instead of 'folder/page'. I've found out that it was because of another .htaccess in 'folder'. I've now managed to make it work. Thanks for your help.